# Finding a minimal cover of a subset of a finite cartesian product by cartesian products

Tags: algorithms, set-cover

Given a subset of a cartesian product $I \times J$ of two finite sets, I wish to find a minimal cover of it by sets which are cartesian products themselves.

For example, given a product between $I=\{A,B,C\}$ and $J=\{1,2,3\}$, I may observe the subset $\{(A,2), (B,3), (B,2)\}$ and try to cover it with a minimal number of cartesian products.

Two ways to do so are $\{A\} \times \{2\} + B \times \{2,3\}$ and $\{A,B\}\times \{2\} + \{B\}\times \{3\}$, both requiring 2 products. A sub-optimal solution may be breaking it into 3 trivial products.

Can such an optimal cover be found efficiently (e.g., in polynomial time)?

Comment: reminds me of this problem, ["factoring cartesian join of bit vectors"](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/13967/factoring-cartesian-bitwise-join-of-bit-vectors) (cstheory.SE, phrased much differently) which has connections to circuit theory lower bounds. what context does your problem arise?

Comment: My context is network security. In a large network with many servers, a security policy defines which may speak with which.
If such a policy is constructed incrementally over a long period of time, (as it usually is) the description of the security policy may be simplified by merging security rules together. I wish to find an optimal such simplification.

Comment: Is it only the number of products you want to minimize?  If so, what's wrong with using $I \times J$ as your cover?  That will cover everything in your subset (and some more).  Do you have a requirement that the solution must not only cover the subset, but must also avoid covering anything outside the subset?

Comment: Also, since this comes from a practical application (and so you probably are looking for practical solutions), can you give a sense of typical parameter sizes?  e.g., the typical size of $|I|$, $|J|$, and your subset, to within an order of magnitude or so; or ranges of typical values?  This might help evaluate which techniques are most likely to be effective. I'm reminded of [logic minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization_for_Boolean_functions), [DNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), and [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: The domain is not $I\times J$ but some $S\subset I\times J$.

$|I|, |J|$ can potentially be as large as $10^9$, but solutions for smaller sizes (say, $10^6$) would be useful as well.

Comment: Perhaps another way to formulate this is the following: Given a bipartite graph $G = (L, R, E)$ find a minimum number of bipartite cliques (or bi-cliques) that cover $E$. Each clique corresponds to a unique product in your cartesian space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NM reformulates this problem in comments as finding minimum number of bipartite cliques (bi-cliques) that cover a bipartite graph. the two sets you mention are the 2 vertex sets of the bipartite graph. the cartesian products of subsets of the two vertex sets are bicliques. wikipedia states this is the [bipartite dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_dimension) problem and is problem GT18 in [Garey and Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Intractability), proved NP complete based on straightforward reformulation of set basis problem SP7.

Comment: What is the best algorithm to find these bipartite cliques in practice?